# Uploading file via base64

Tags: python, django, base64

I'm using django-avatars to handle user profile avatars for my website.  I'm currently developing a native Android app for the site, which includes the ability for users to upload an avatar.  I'm passing the image data in via a get parameter encoded in base 64.  In my Django view, I have

```
data = base64.b64decode(request.POST['data'])    
out = open("etc/test.jpeg", "wb")
out.write(data)
out.close()
```

to decode the image.  This is working fine (test.jpeg is the file that I want it to be), but I'm having trouble tying this into django-avatars.

Looking through the source of django-avatars, the following is used to create a new avatar:

```
avatar = Avatar(
    user = request.user,
    primary = True,
)
image_file = request.FILES['avatar']
avatar.avatar.save(image_file.name, image_file)
avatar.save()
```

My question is, how can I convert my file data into the required request.FILES format, (or what's the easiest way to rewrite the save method to accept my format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`request.FILES` elements are file-likes in a wrapper. Stick the file data in a `StringIO`, pass it to the [`django.core.files.File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File) constructor, then pass *that* to `save()`.

Comment: I'm having trouble constructing the django File object.  I have http://dpaste.com/743542/, which produces this error on the avatar.avatar.save() line : http://dpaste.com/743541/

Comment: You'll need to assign the length of the data to the `size` attribute of the StringIO object.